# Why does a Form Region in Outlook 2007 Plugin keep a reference to the underlying object open?

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-2007, outlook-addin, outlook-form

I've created an empty Outlook 2007 Plugin Project in Visual Studio 2008 (SP1). Then I added a new Form Region (Contact type, Adjoined, otherwise defaults) and then I run the project.

Outlook opens, I go to a contact change a couple of things, then click on the close button. Outlook asks if I want to save, I choose No.

My understanding is that this should reset all changes I made. But if I re-open that same contact all my changes are still there. If I close the whole outlook it will re-prompt me to save the contact I changed.

This leads me to thinking that the default Form Region template actually keeps a reference to the Contact it is being shown for and not disposing of it after the form region is closed. This causes the contact to be in memory and not simply disposed after closing the form.

Can anyone reproduce, or is it a feature? Any way to get around this?